# How to fix this error

Tags: python, twilio

I'm using windows7 64bit and Python 2.7.11

I have successfully installed the twilio but I have an error with the first line of code

```
from twilio.rest import Client

# Your Account SID from twilio.com/console
account_sid = "AC3902a3c28c6cf74a72a464c9062f6979"
# Your Auth Token from twilio.com/console
auth_token  = "your_auth_token"

client = Client(account_sid, auth_token)

message = client.messages.create(
    to="+15558675309", 
    from_="+15017250604",
    body="Hello from Python!")

print(message.sid)
```

Here is the error I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\python\sendText.py", line 1, in <module>
    from twilio.rest import Client
ImportError: cannot import name Client
```

Comment: Are you using IDE or command line? because the same code works just fine in pyCharm.

Comment: Please mention `twilio version`

Comment: Where's your Python shebang, consider using one maybe (even on Windows); check permissions too.

Comment: @DineshKumar I'm using command line opening new empty file I write my code in the file and then run it with f5 (run Module)

Comment: @JkShaw my twilio version is 6.3.dev0

Comment: @l'L'l if I understood your question well my shebang is #!C:\Python27 python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On looking at source files of `twilio-6.3 dev0`. You would come to see that there is no `Client` class exposed in `__init__.py` under `twilio.rest`, the contents are as follows:

```
_hush_pyflakes = [set_twilio_proxy, TwilioRestClient,
                  TwilioConversationsClient, TwilioIpMessagingClient,
                  TwilioLookupsClient, TwilioPricingClient,
                  TwilioTaskRouterClient, TwilioTrunkingClient]
```

As you can see above instead of `Client`, `TwilioRestClient` is being used.

So, for your case you need to use `TwilioRestClient` for your code to work as follows:

```
from twilio.rest import TwilioRestClient
client = TwilioRestClient("ACCOUNT_SID", "AUTH_TOKEN")
```

Comment: I have just did so before I got your answer! The very strange thing that I got this lines of code from the official documentation of twilio. Any how Thank you a lot )

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

The [twilio-6.3 dev0 tag on GitHub](https://github.com/twilio/twilio-python/tree/6.3.dev0) has not been updated since January 2016. I don't know what it's doing there and will try to find out from the team responsible.

I recommend that you use the latest release version of the [Twilio python helper which is currently 6.1.2](https://www.twilio.com/docs/libraries/python). Then your original code, in which you called `from twilio.rest import Client`, will work.